# Counting DOF according to a probabilistic graphical model (MRF, BN)

Tags: statistics, bayesian-network

Given the graphical model of a probability distribution, either a Markov Random field (*MRF*) or a Bayesian Net (*BN*), how does one count the **maximal number of degrees of freedom** for all probability functions compatible with (i.e. with at least the set of indepencies encoded in) the graphical model?

For example, consider the MRF of three random variables $X_1 \leftrightarrow X_2 \leftrightarrow X_3$, where each $X_i \in S_i$ can take one of $D_i = |S_i|$ possible values. Here are two constructive attempts at counting the number of degrees of freedom $\#\mathrm{DOF}$, which disagree with eachother. Each time, we count the maximal number of degrees of freedom in each conditional probability and sum them up:

- $P(X_1,X_2,X_3) = P(X_1) P(X_2|X_1) P(X_3|X_2)$ gives $\# \mathrm{DOF} = D_1 + D_1 D_2 + D_3 D_2$
- $P(X_1,X_2,X_3) = P(X_2) P(X_1|X_2) P(X_3|X_2)$ gives $\# \mathrm{DOF} = D_2 + D_1 D_2 + D_3 D_2$

Why do the two disagree? Is $\#\mathrm{DOF}$ ill-defined, or do the two decompositions not correctly encode the exact same set of independencies from the graphical model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation of both $\# \mathrm{DOF}$ is wrong, since the number of degrees of freedom is further reduced by normalization. The correct expressions which do account for normalization (subtracting 1 degree of freedom for each distribution) are respectively:

- $\# \mathrm{DOF} = (D_1 - 1) + D_1 ( D_2 - 1 ) + D_2 ( D_3 - 1 )$
- $\# \mathrm{DOF} = (D_2 - 1) + D_2 ( D_1 - 1 ) + D_2 ( D_3 - 1 )$

Contrary to the above, these two are both equivalent to $D_2 ( D_1 + D_3 ) - 1$. Curiously, the difference in $\# \mathrm{DOF}$ between the non-normalized and the normalized version apparently depends on the chosen decomposition.